# Is it Possible to use Python that is installed from the NuGet Unity Package Manager, for all platforms in a Unity game project?

Tags: unity, scripting

Hi I've installed NuGetForUnity that is a Unity package to my Unity game project from the url: https://github.com/GlitchEnzo/NuGetForUnity/tree/master and there are so many NuGet packages are available to use in my Unity game project. But I don't know whether the Python 3 package can be used for all the platforms that my game runs on or not.

So is it possible to use Python 3 that is installed from the NuGetForUnity Package Manager, for all the platforms that my Unity game runs on?

If not, for what platforms and what platform not?

Comment: Isn't this something that runs on your server? If I don't read that wrong, it would not matter for the platform, more if your server is Linux, Mac or Windows and the NuGet works there.

Comment: @Zibelas Aren't some NuGet packages for iOS and Android?

Comment: Maybe, but that is not what NuGetForUnity provides. From how I understand it and from the github: `NuGetForUnity provides a visual editor window to see available packages on the server, see installed packages, and see available package updates. A visual interface is also provided to create and edit .nuspec files in order to define and publish your own NuGet packages from within Unity.` It allows you to grab them, nothing says that you can run them.